# How can a foreign pilot get renter's insurance in the USA?

Tags: general-aviation, usa, renters-insurance

I'm about to go to the United States and do some flying. I sorted out my FAA license conversion but I was wondering how to get aircraft renter's insurance. It seems that some schools / clubs require this, and it's not included in the hire contract.

I googled a bit but it's seems that all the policies are for US residents and annual contracts. I'm more interested in a month or so.

Anybody else who's had this problem? Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you looking to rent an aircraft from a school and fly with that for a month? If so, tell me I'm currently staying with a flight school so I might be able to get you some information.

Comment: Hi Maverick283. Thanks. I plan to hire a plane (172-ish) just for a few days (back to home airport every evening) total time probably around 5h. Nothing special really.

Comment: Do you already have renter's insurance in your own country? If so, can you get US coverage added to your existing policy? If you're going to be using the same FBO/school for a month, you could ask them to contact their insurance company as well.

Answer (score 3):

Most flight schools in the US have an easy policy for renting out their planes:

You go there, you do a checkout flight on an airplane with one of their instructors, and you can go ahead and fly as much as you want.

The planes are then insured by the flight school, and you pay for the insurance by paying an hourly fee to the flight school. The checkout flight is necessary for the insurance, and is most of the time valid for 90 days. After that, another checkout flight might be required.

You, though, might not be included in that insurance. If something happens to you, the flight school's insurance will probably not cover the costs you might have.

I don't want to advertise on here, but for if you are interested I can show you a nice flight school in Florida.

Comment: I don't know about "most", but definitely enough that you should be able to find one. The devil is in the details a though: Some of these policies cover the school and the aircraft, but not the pilot. As with all insurance you should read the policy carefully before you rely on it.

Comment: Thats a good point, didnt even think about that and will add it to the answer!

Comment: If you damage an aircraft the FBO's insurance company is probably going to start by going after the pilot personally for the money and they'll only pay out themselves if they can't recover it that way. So it isn't just about "if something happens to you"; you can still be held liable even if the FBO's insurance would cover the damage. This is why it's very difficult to give any useful answers about insurance: policies are different everywhere.